# Saving Workbook Referencing Several Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have been struggling with this for the past several hours.
I am wanting to save a Workbook by referencing 4 different cell values. The following is the code that is not working.

```
Sub SU_CreateSaveWorkbook_Macro() 'Save to folder and ask which folder
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim filename1 As String
Dim filename2 As String
Dim filename3 As String
Dim filename4 As String

filename1 = Sheet15.Range("C12")
filename2 = Sheet15.Range("C6")
filename3 = Sheet15.Range("C7")
filename4 = Sheet15.Range("C8")

Dim SvName As String
SvName = filename1 & "_" & filename2 & "_" & filename3 & filename4 & Format(Now, " mm-dd-yyyy ")

On Error Resume Next
    userResponce = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(SvName)
On Error GoTo 0
If userResponce = False Then
    Exit Sub
Else
Sheet15.Range("K19").Value = "1"
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify: Is it 4 copies of ThisWorkbook with use of different names you want? Note: Filenames also have specials characters not allowed to be used in the filename if that is what you struggle with.

Comment: I am wanting to create 1 copy of ThisWorkBook. The cells being referenced are standard "text" cells.

Comment: Ok - After Format you need to have two parentheses like: Now() to get the date value of today returned.

Comment: @SveinArneHylland That's not true. But since OP is after the date, instead of `Now`, he can use just `Date`.

Comment: You didn't tell us what's happening, is there an error (share its number and description)? Use `Debug.Print userResponce` or `MsgBox userResponce` to see if the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

After Format you need to have two parentheses like: Now() to get the date value of today returned and it also needs to include filetype extension .xlsm. (unless you want it saved as a .pdf)

```
SvName = filename1 & "_" & filename2 & "_" & filename3 & filename4 & Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy")&".xlsm"
' This will save it on Path if filename1 includes the Path (Like C:/Temp)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb
    .SaveAs FileName:= _
        SvName
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance. The above code works GREAT!!!